# Use Chebyshev's inequality to ﬁnd a lower bound of a Chi-Square Distribution

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions, random-variables, chi-squared

I'm trying to solve the following exercise but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is right.

"Let $X$ be an r.v. distributed as $\chi_{40}^{2}$. Use Tchebichev’s inequality
in order to ﬁnd a lower bound for the probability $P(|(X/40) − 1| ≤ 0.5)$,
and compare this bound with the exact value found from the $\chi^{2}$ Distribution Table."

Considering that $\mu=40$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{2\times40}$ my approach was turning the inequality into:

$P(-20\leq|X-40|\leq 20)\geq 1-\frac{1}{k^{2}}$

In order to obtain:

$P(|X-40| ≤ 20)\geq 1-\frac{1}{k^{2}}$

$P(|X-40| ≤ 20)\geq 1-\frac{1}{2.236^{2}}=0.8$

But this result doesn't match with the Distribution Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First recall Markov's inequality:

> If $X$ is a nonnegative random variable with finite mean, then for all $a>0$, we have $$\mathbb P(X\geqslant a) \leqslant \frac{\mathbb E[X]}{a}.$$

This follows from observing that
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^\infty x\ \mathsf d F(x) \geqslant \int_a^\infty x\ \mathsf dF(x) \geqslant a\int_a^\infty\ \mathsf dF(x) = a\cdot\mathbb P(X\geqslant a)
$$

Chebyshev's inequality states:

> If $X$ is square-integrable with variance $\sigma^2$, then for any $a>0$ we have
> $$
> \mathbb P\left(|X-\mathbb E[X]|\geqslant a\sigma \right)\leqslant \frac1{a^2}.
>  $$

This follows immediately from Markov's inequality:

\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left(|X-\mathbb E[X]|\geqslant a\sigma \right) &= \mathbb P\left(|X-\mathbb E[X]|^2\geqslant a^2\sigma^2 \right)\\
&\leqslant \frac{\mathbb E[|X-\mathbb E[X]|^2]}{a^2\sigma^2}\\
&= a^2.
\end{align}

Since $X$ is an absolutely continuous random variable, we have
$$
1 = \mathbb P(|X-E[X]|\geqslant a\sigma) + \mathbb P(|X-E[X]|\leqslant a\sigma),
$$
so that
$$
\mathbb P(|X-E[X]|\leqslant a\sigma)\geqslant 1-\frac1{a^2}.
$$

In this example, it is clear that
$$
\{|(X/40)-1|\leqslant 1/2 \}= \{|X-40|\leqslant 20\}.
$$
Since $X\sim\chi_{40}^2$, we have $\mathbb E[X] = 40$ and $\sigma^2 = 2\mathbb E[X] = 80$ so that $\sigma = 2\sqrt{20}$. Now, $20 = \sqrt{20}/2\cdot\sigma$, so we conclude that
$$
\mathbb P(|X/40-1|\leqslant 1/2) \geqslant 1 - \geqslant \frac 15 = \frac45.
$$

Indeed this inequality is valid, as if we compute the actual probability from the density of $X$, we find that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P[|X-40|\leqslant 20] &= \int_{(20,60)} f_X(x)\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \int_{20}^{60} \frac{x^{19} e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{2^{20} ((20-1)!)} \, dx\\
&= \frac{325946782122931}{14849255421}e^{-10}-\frac{529037857402226791}{2263261}e^{-30}\\
&\approx 0.974672.
\end{align}

It is important to note that such simply derived tail bounds, while easy to apply, need not be "tight." For example, if $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent Bernoulli random variables with success probabilities $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ and $X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, with $\mu:=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i$ then Markov's inequality yields
$$
\mathbb P(X>n/2) \leqslant \frac{\mu}{n/2} = \frac 2n\mu.
$$
Clearly this bound is only useful for $0<\mu<\frac n2$. Now, if $\varphi:[0,\infty]\to\mathbb R$ is a monotone increasing function with $\varphi(a)>0$ and $X$ only assumed to be integrable (not necessarily non-negative), then applying Markov's inequality to $\varphi(|X|)$ and $\varphi(a)$, we find that
$$
\mathbb E[|X|\geqslant a] = \mathbb P(\varphi(|X|\geqslant \varphi(a))\leqslant\frac{\mathbb E[\varphi(|X|)}{\varphi(a)}.\tag1
$$
Take $\varphi$ to be the map $x\mapsto e^{\theta x}$ - then $\mathbb E[\varphi(|X|)]$ is the moment-generating function of $|X|$. Then $(1)$ implies that
$$
\mathbb P(X\geqslant a)\leqslant e^{-\theta a} \mathbb E\left[\prod_{i=1}^n e^{\theta X_i}\right],
$$
and hence
$$
\mathbb P(X\geqslant a)\leqslant\min_{\theta >0} e^{-\theta a}\mathbb E\left[\prod_{i=1}^n e^{\theta X_i}\right],
$$
where
For each $i$ we have
$$
\mathbb E[e^{\theta X_i}] = 1-p_i+p_ie^{\theta} = 1+p_i(e^\theta-1)\leqslant e^{p_i(e^\theta-1)},
$$
which converges for all real $\theta$. Since the moment-generating function of the (finite) sum of random variables is simply the product of the individual moment-generating functions (a good exercise to prove), we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[e^{\theta X}] &= \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[e^{\theta X_i}]\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n (1-p_i+p_ie^{\theta})\\
&\leqslant \prod_{i=1}^n e^{p_i(e^\theta-1)}\\
&\leqslant e^{(e^\theta-1)\mu}.
\end{align}
As this is true for all $\theta>0$, it follows that
$$
\mathbb E[e^{\theta X}] \leqslant \min_{\theta>0} e^{(e^\theta-1)\mu}.
$$
Fix $\delta>0$ and set $a=(1+\delta)\mu$, then
$$
\mathbb P(X\geqslant (1+\delta)\mu) \leqslant\min_{\theta>0} e^{-\theta(1+\delta)\mu}  e^{(e^\theta-1)\mu}.\tag2
$$
The motivation for minimizing over $\theta$ is to make the bound as tight as possible (this particular method is known as the Chernoff bound). Indeed, differentiating the right-hand side of $(2)$ gives
$$
\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf d\theta} \left[e^{-\theta(1+\delta)\mu}  e^{(e^\theta-1)\mu}\right] = e^{\left(e^{\theta }-1\right) \mu -(\delta +1) \theta  \mu } \left(e^{\theta } \mu -(\delta +1) \mu \right),
$$
which is equal to zero precisely when $\theta = \log(1+\delta)$. Plugging in this value of $\theta$, we have
$$
\mathbb P(X\geqslant (1+\delta)\mu) \leqslant\left(\frac{e^\delta}{(1+\delta)^{1+\delta}} \right)^\mu\tag3.
$$
Taking the logarithm of the right-hand side of $(3)$ yields
$$
\mu(\delta-(1+\delta)\log(1+\delta)).\tag4
$$
Now, comparing the series expansions
$$
\log(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n
$$
and
$$
\frac x{1+x/2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}2^{-(n+1)},
$$
we see that for $x>0$,
$$
\log(1+x)\geqslant \frac x{1+x/2}.\tag 5
$$
Applying the inequality from $(5)$ to $(4)$, we obtain
$$
\mu(\delta-(1+\delta)\log(1+\delta))\leqslant -\frac{\delta^2}{2+\delta}\mu.
$$
Putting this all together, we find the following bound for the upper tail:
$$
\mathbb P(X\geqslant (1+\delta)\mu) \leqslant e^{-\frac{\delta^2}{2+\delta}\mu}.
$$
An analogous argument leads to the following bound for the lower tail:
$$
\mathbb P(X\leqslant (1-\delta)\mu) \geqslant 1 - e^{-\mu\delta^2/2}.
$$

It is considerably more difficult to derive these bounds for the $\chi^2$ distribution, but the result is that for $0<\delta<1$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X\geqslant (1+\delta)\mu )&\leqslant e^{-\mu(\varepsilon^2(1-\varepsilon)/4}\\
\mathbb P(X\leqslant (1-\delta)\mu )&\leqslant 1- e^{-\mu(\varepsilon^2(1-\varepsilon)/4}
\end{align}
Here $\mu = 40$, $\delta=\frac12$, and $\varepsilon=\frac12$. Plugging those values in results in the bound
$$
\mathbb P(|X-40|\leqslant 20) \geqslant 1 - e^{-\frac54} \approx 0.713495,
$$
which indeed is a tighter bound.